# Where is the last boot log of android?

Tags: android

Assuming slot A can boot successfuly, but slot B will fail. How can I find the failure reason of slot B after slot A started?

```bash
adb logcat --last | tee logcat.log
logcat: Logcat read failure: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:bootable/recovery/recovery-persist.cpp

```cpp
constexpr const char* LAST_LOG_FILE = "/data/misc/recovery/last_log";
constexpr const char* LAST_PMSG_FILE = "/sys/fs/pstore/pmsg-ramoops-0";
constexpr const char* LAST_KMSG_FILE = "/data/misc/recovery/last_kmsg";
constexpr const char* LAST_CONSOLE_FILE = "/sys/fs/pstore/console-ramoops-0";
constexpr const char* ALT_LAST_CONSOLE_FILE = "/sys/fs/pstore/console-ramoops";
```